# why is header() function displaying A sql error

Tags: php

```
<?php
include_once( 'mysqlconnect.php' );

$id=$_POST['id']; //line 8

header("location:settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php?id='$id'");

?>
```

output:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your //MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8''' at line 1

I know my error is at the `?id='$id'` but what I don't understand and my question is: why is it displaying output: You have an error in your SQL syntax?...

by the way both mysqlconnect.php as the name suggests is a connection script and $id is gotten from a post request from another page. settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php is an empty script and they all are error free

Comment: What happens in settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php?

Comment: Shiow the code for `settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php`

Comment: May be you would like to check inside `mysqlconnect.php` file line:8.

Comment: Why you are connecting to database when you need redirection with simple post!

Comment: Totally vulnerable to attacks, moreover you are using $id in your query to fetch records somewhere, which is causing you that error

Comment: I also thinks the culprit thing is mysqlconnect.php

Comment: Though the error may be caused by the `'` marks you're wrapping around `$id` in your redirect

Comment: You most probably make a get request from the form you used to post to this as an action settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when your header function is called, PHP engine has started executing code on settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php page and on that page SQL error is there, so it is displaying SQL error.

Please note that there is no error in header function here, as the syntax you used is perfectly valid but may not be logically correct. So next page did not get required id value due to single quotes used and hence generated SQL error.

Hope this clarifies the things.

Comment: Problem is here include_once( 'mysqlconnect.php' ); header function will simple redirect to any url provided.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir This is more of guessing based on experience, because we have not seen the code of both pages mysqlconnect.php and view.php.

Comment: header function stops its execution when there is pre header generated, putting some html/ string generates header of text/html. In this case include_once( 'mysqlconnect.php' ); is generating some html.

Comment: My answer is based on user input : "I know my error is at the ?id='$id' " , How can you be sure about mysqlconnect.php is generating html ?

Comment: include_once( 'mysqlconnect.php' ); is perfectly ok...just a connection script. i've been using it for other scripts... And how on earth is view needed? the error is generated in this page and doesn't move any futher...but for clarity sake its just an empty page

Answer (score 1):

You don't need apostrophes.

```
<?php
  include_once( 'mysqlconnect.php' );

  $id=$_POST['id']; //8

  header("location:settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php?id=$id");
?>
```

With your code, `$_GET['id']` will somewhere be getting `string(3) '8'` and trying to use it in your SQL.

I agree with some of the other comments, this is totally open to abuse. Please think about using post variables instead of get variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect database

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    header("Location: settings_pay_roll.allowance.general.view.php?id=$id");
}
else
{
    echo 'Post is missing';
}
?>
```